# Why alert in useEffect run before console in return statement in a functional component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

According to react docs, If we don't specify the second argument in the `useEffect` hook it will behave like `componentDidMount` and `componentDidUpdate`

> By using useEffect Hook, you tell React that your component needs to do something after render - [react docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html)
>
> **Does useEffect run after every render?** Yes! By default, it runs both after the first render and after every update.

That means in both cases useEffect will run after the initial render and after the update.

```
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";

export default function App() {
  const [checked, setChecked] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("useEffect statement");
    alert("Alert in useEffect hook");
  });

  function onChecked() {
    setChecked((state) => {
      return !state;
    });
  }

  return (
    <>
      {console.log("return statement")}
      {alert("Alert in return hook")}
      <input value="checked" onChange={onChecked} type="checkbox" />
      <h1> {checked ? "checked" : "Not-checked"} </h1>
    </>
  );
}
```

[codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/zen-brahmagupta-x5uu6?file=/src/App.js)

I was expecting the result to be in the following sequence:

- console data from the return statement
- alert in the return statement
- console data from useEffect hook
- alert in useEffect hook

But what I got is in the following sequence:

- alert in the return statement
- alert in useEffect hook
- console data from the return statement
- console data from useEffect hook

Comment: because console methods are asynchronous and run in its own process

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The component is rendered to React's virtual DOM during the "render phase" before it is "rendered" to the DOM during the commit phase.

[image]

Notice that the `render` method occurs during the "render phase" and that it may be paused, aborted, or restarted by React. React updates DOM and refs during the "commit phase", and also note that this is when the UI can work with the DOM and run side-effects.

> I was expecting the result to be in the following sequence:
>
> - console data from the return statement
> - alert in the return statement
> - console data from useEffect hook
> - alert in useEffect hook
>
> But what I got is in the following sequence:
>
> - alert in the return statement
> - alert in useEffect hook
> - console data from the return statement
> - console data from useEffect hook

You saw the unintentional side-effects in your "render" method being run during the "render phase" and then your `useEffect` side-effects after the DOM was updated. The reason you see the logs *after* the alerts is likely due to the console's asynchronicity and that the alert blocks the main thread.